# Prettifying a URL is failing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a URL

> http://domain.com/directory/

There is an index.php inside of directory which allows me to access that url as it is

But say I want to access `http://domain.com/directory/?id=123` but from this `http://domain.com/directory/123`

I tried the below both in the root and also in the `directory` folder but still no luck

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]*)$ /directory/?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in `/directory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```